# React component does no re-render when it is swapped with the same one

Tags: reactjs

Please consider the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Component = ({ title }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>count up</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const changeComponent = () => {
    setIndex(c => (c === 1 ? 0 : 1));
  };

  const components = [
    {
      render: () => <Component title="one" />
    },
    {
      render: () => <Component title="two" />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={changeComponent}>toggle component</button>
      {components[index].render()}
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hermann-si7cn

When you click `toggle component`, title changes, but component is not unmounted, you can see it because count is not reset.

How to make it so that new component is mounted on `toggle component` click?

Comment: The sandbox you link shows that each component mounts and unmounts on button click. I guess I'm not understanding what you expect?

Comment: @BrianThompson, sorry I think sandbox was modified, changed it back

Answer (score 2):

React needs a way to differentiate one component instance from the other. This will fix it

```js
const components = [
  {
    render: () => <Component key={1} title="one" />
  },
  {
    render: () => <Component key={2} title="two" />
  }
];
```

Its the same reason react requires dynamically rendered lists to have a `key` prop. It informs react of which component to update.